# WRF736SDAM Whirlpool Refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

I received my refrigerator and after having it in the house by taking doors off and leaning it on side, 30 minutes late I plugged it in not knowing until after 24 hours that I was supposed to wait before plug it in.  The manuel was missing.  Do I unplug it and wait another 24 hours and plug it back in.

Comment: The idea of waiting 24 hours is so that the coolant can settle after the refrigerator has been tossed around. But as Paul Logan says below, if it's working OK, then there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

If it is cooling it is fine.  If it is not cooling unplug it for 24-hrs.  Good Luck.